# No module named 'util'

Tags: python

I have this error:

```
from shop.util.fields import CurrencyField
ImportError: No module named 'shop.util'
```

...in `models.py` file.

And when I tried to just import `util` I got this:

```
ImportError: No module named 'util'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you also share how your .py files are organized?

Comment: Are these modules written by you? If yes, how is the directory structure? If not, where did you get them?

Comment: Is shop at application's top level? or is it inside another module?